# Has google changed crawlers in a way that could lead to the 404 growth?

Tags: seo, http-status-code-404, google-search-console

Since yesterday i'm seeing growing number of 404 errors on our website. It is very strange because we don't have those pages which are reported as missing. Also we didn't released any code changes on that day.

Google Webmaster tool is reporting those errors, but when I look into the pages which are linking to the missing urls - there is no a such links. Could this be a Google Crawlers issue?

[image]

404 URL:

http://www.justanswer.co.uk/boat/home-improvement/homework/writing

Linked from:

http://www.justanswer.co.uk/boat/home-improvement/homework
http://www.justanswer.co.uk/boat/home-improvement/hvac

Answer (score 2):

It seems that You have CORS issues doing cross-domain javascript.

> https://www.facebook.com/connect/ping?client_id=172525162793917&domain=www.justanswer.co.uk&origin=1&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fstaticxx.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D42%23cb%3Df316e5bca883b5%26domain%3Dwww.justanswer.co.uk%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.justanswer.co.uk%252Ff50e0366c05c14%26relation%3Dparent&response_type=token%2Csigned_request%2Ccode&sdk=joey

is saying that

> *Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.*